# Unity: How to change/scale game for iPad AND iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, unity-game-engine, device

Ok, Ive posted to Unity also but I am having trouble supporting both iPad and iPhone with my iOS build.

In the past, my games have scaled pretty well just due to Unity, however now testing (the game is finished) there are 2 (relatively small) problem when I deploy to iPad simulator (I don't have an actual iPad and am not sure whether this may be causing the issue) -

First my splash screen is being cropped too tight on the sides, even though I thought Unity scaled this. This might be simple as putting in a resized launch screen, but wanted to note this.

The big problem - my game is essentially cropped too tight on the sides and too long on the vertical (due to screen size), meaning some buttons I have positioned via animations, etc on the sides aren't visible. Also, the game looks overall off.

What is the most efficient way of fixing this? I was thinking of going the route of getting the active device via code and changing things that way, but that would be a hassle. Is there a way to have the game more evenly scale for iPad, maybe change the camera field of view so it zooms out?

It was built for iPhone and works well on all iPhones.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-UIMultiResolution.html) could help?

Answer (score 0):

The [Unity UI System](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UISystem.html) is responsive and fast to implements, is recomended to create menus and interfaces.

but...

you can move the main camera to back of the objects, or changing the `size` (to ortographic camera) and `fieldOfView` (to perspective camera), this value represents a scale of view port of camera.